# Reading RFID tag using Android Device via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-bluetooth, rfid

I am currently developing app with target device like Samsung Tablet 3.0 and it does not have NFC feature in it but it has Bluetooth .

I would like to know can I read a RFID tag using Bluetooth if yes , does any one have code .

Have gone through various stack questions and it seems , it requires NFC technology also got a code for it [NFC CODE](http://androidworkshop.tumblr.com/)  . But can a support for bluetooth communication is possible

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry but this is absolutely not possible:

NFC is sending with a frequency around 13.56 MHZ whereas Bluetooth uses 2.4 GHz to 2.5 GHz. Totaly different standards.

Resource: Wikipedia [Wikipedialink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)